# Heroku throws error missing module on Windows

Tags: windows, heroku, deployment, cloud, heroku-cli

I just installed Heroku CLI via the official installer from their [website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install). But when I try for example the command `heroku login` I get the following exception:

```
module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@heroku-cli/color'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Local\heroku\client\6.16.8-ae149be\node_modules\@cli-engine\engine\lib\cli.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
```

Maybe I am missing some requirements, but on the official website I have not found any.